# What's a better choice for "a variety of mediums"?

Tags: ambiguity

I read the following in a workplace communication this morning:

> We plan to communicate our re-entry strategies and schedules
> throughout the summer (using **a variety of mediums**) to help everyone
> plan accordingly.

I know what's meant, but "a variety of mediums" puts me in mind of a tag-team séance.  Although "media" might be the more correct plural in the intended sense, it has the [recent?] implication of "mass media", which is not what's meant here.

What might have been a better way to write this?

BTW, this was not *my* sentence, it came in an official communication from the C-suite at my employer.  It seemed "off" to me, but I couldn't think of a better way to put it.

Answer (score 0):

"...a number of different channels" might work for you. It gets away from using the overworked word 'media' and also the almost entirely incorrect word 'mediums'. As you suggest the only correct use of 'mediums' is to refer to people who are able, or at least claim to be able, to communicate with the spirit world.